# Regex for numeric range from negative numbers?

Tags: regex

I want to validate a number using regex.. the condition is number can be from any negative 3 digit values to positive 3 digit.. but cannot be zero.

can someone please help me to get regex condition for this.

Comment: Why not just parse the number and then check it in code?

Comment: Thanks Anon.. but i need regex statement.. I have to pass it to a function.

Comment: regex is a string parser, do you mean you have a string representation of a number that you cannot parse as a number? what language are you using? Anon has a good point, this case should not require regex. please add more information to the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There it´s
It can or not start with the negative symbol, followed by a number between 1 and 9 ant then can be 0 to 2 of any number.

```
^\-?[1-9]\d{0,2}$
```

Update: And the following regex also allows decimals

```
^\-?[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d*)?$
```

Comment: Thanks pcofe.. how to take care of decimals in this expression ?

Comment: There it´s ^\-?[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d*)?$

Comment: How it can be converted to use all numbers ie 0-9 and -1 ie only -1 or any other no.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are dealing with whole integers, and your number don't mix with other texts, you can try this

```
^-?[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$
```

I agree with Anon, it is much better to read the String, and convert it to int to do the comparison, if you have predictable inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I used this with the .NET System.Text.RegularExpressions to match positive or negative decimals (numbers).

```
(\d+|-\d+)
```

Comment: What if just: `-?\d+` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have some experiments about regex in django url, which required from negative to positive numbers

```
^(?P<pid>(\-\d+|\d+))$
```

Let's we focused on this `(\-\d+|\d+)` part and ignoring others, this semicolon `|` means **OR** in regex, then if we got negative value it will be matched with this `\-\d+` part, and positive value into this `\d+` part

Answer (score 0):

I think in all the above input like this is allowed -2-22,2-22 which is a minor bug.Review this as well :-

```
[\-]?[0-9]*$/
```

even smaller :

```
/^[\-]?\d*$/
```

Comment: Why not just `-?` instead of `[\-]?`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me as the best is:

> ^[+-]?[0-9]*$

I was checking regex datatype and the range of positive and negative number.

This solution worked.

Comment: This is matching `0`, `123456` but it shouldn't.