# How to add !=-1 to regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regular expression to check for non characters and only 2 digits in a string:

```
var RegularExpression = /^\d{2}$/
```

How do I modify it to accept "-1"?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for numeric range from negative numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024535/regex-for-numeric-range-from-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *only* want to accept any string consisting of two digits or the exact string `"-1"`, use an alternation (`|`), like this:

```
/^(\d{2}|-1)$/
```

Or if you'd like to accept any string consisting or two digits or a string consisting of a negative sign and one digit (i.e. any number from `-9` to `99`), use a character class (`[…]`), like this:

```
/^[-\d]\d$/
```

Answer (score 0):

like this maybe:

```
/^\d{2}$|^-1$/
```